# Joining on 1 column across 4 tables - Mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I'm going over some SQL I wrote a while ago that joins 4 tables on a common ID column. I'm getting a little paranoid about my join, and I hope someone can just clear this simple concept up for me:

```
SELECT A.adata, B.bdata, C.cdata, D.ddata 
FROM taba A, tabb B, tabc C, tabd D
WHERE A.id=B.id AND B.id=C.id AND C.id=D.id
AND A.id=C.id AND A.id=D.id AND B.id=D.id
```

Do I need all those AND clauses, or can I eliminate the last 3, like this:

```
SELECT A.adata, B.bdata, C.cdata, D.ddata 
FROM taba A, tabb B, tabc C, tabd D
WHERE A.id=B.id AND B.id=C.id AND C.id=D.id
```

Although I've successfully tested the smaller query on my dataset and it appears to yield the same result, I don't want to have some incomplete SQL come back to haunt me. On the other hand, I don't want to load up on unnecessary conditions. Let me know if I can provide additional information.

-- UPDATE, thanks for answers everyone. About the tables: they are relatively static although some values within the rows change throughout the day. Each table A, B, C, D stores different information about OBJECT, and the OBJECT ID is common across all 4, so it's very straightforward here.

Comment: The joins are entirely dependent on your table structure. A properly normalized design would not have tables A/C, A/D, and B/D directly dependent on each other, but only indirectly dependent via the linking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution to make it far easier to read is to use the ISO/ANSI Join syntax:

```
Select A.adata, B.bdata, C.cdata, D.ddata 
From taba As A
    Inner Join tabb As B
        On B.id = A.id
    Inner Join tabc As C
        On C.id = B.id
    Inner Join tabd As D
        On D.id = C.Id
```

Comment: I like this, but wouldn't you capitalize all the keywords too?

Comment: @colinmarc - That's a stylistic preference. One that IMO is no longer required, makes it harder to read and harder to type.

Comment: I'd agree with harder to type, but definitely not easier to read. To each his own I guess =)

Comment: so aside from readability...is the answer below about the "transitive relationship" accurate?

Comment: @colinmarc - The problem I have with capitalization is that the stuff I care about most is the tables and columns and secondarily the keywords. With modern IDE (and website) color coding, it isn't necessary IMO.

Comment: @Steve M I'm not actually sure. I'm pretty sure your second version is identical to your first and also to Thomas's, at least in mysql, but I've always wondered myself if there's a functional difference.

Comment: @Steve M - Based on what little of the schema you have shown us, yes, it should be the case that the relationships are transitive. Obviously, having the schema and relationships to inspect would allows us to say definitively.

Comment: @Steve M - It is worth asking how it is that you have instances of A directly related to instances of B,C,and D and those three are all related to each other on the same key value. It'd almost require a four-way 1:1 relationship.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your help. I updated the question, but I think I have a good understanding of this now.

Answer (score 0):

Your second version takes advantage of the [transitive relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) between the table columns.

A simpler way to think about it would be.

`A = 1`, `B = A`, therefore `B = 1`

Answer (score 0):

I agree you should use the `INNER JOIN` syntax, to make it easier to follow.

But you should also keep in mind that those AND clauses may be used by the optimizer. Without knowing how your tables are built I can't say for sure. But in general, if you tell the database to join based on two columns, it will attempt to use indexes, if they exist. If you replace those using the "transitive property", then you might make the query run slower.

Just a warning. It depends on your specific table structure.

If you tested it and it runs just as fast, it may be fine. But are the tables growing? Might it fail over time?  I would be concerned about that, and test it with very large tables before making the change.